# How does DNS server know take ServerName from httpd.conf though it is not configured in "/etc/hosts"

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost

I just dont get how my browser is able to route to correct path....when I give ServerName of a virtual host....even though it is not configured in "/etc/hosts"

Please explain me.....

This is the Virtualhost Iam talking abt

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example
  DocumentRoot "<*path*>"
  RailsEnv development
  <Directory "<*path*>"
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what is the IP of your server

Comment: its on localhost

Comment: That's not an IP address...

Comment: I mean....my server is on local machine....i.e., 127.0.0.1

Comment: I'm beginning to doubt the validity of this question being asked here.  I would go out on a limb and suggest you aren't a sysadmin. http://serverfault.com/faq

Answer (score 5):

The DNS server doesn't take ServerName from httpd.conf

Your browser doesn't route the request, the web server returns the correct page based in part on the Host HTTP Header sent by the browser.

When you type a URL in your browser and hit enter, the name is resolved to IP using DNS, and the browser sends an HTTP request to the IP returned from the DNS query.

[HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers#Requests) form the core of the HTTP request. One of these is the Host, or domain name you typed in the browser.

Using an example Virtual Host definition.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The ServerName directive within your Virtual Host configuration is matched against the Host HTTP Header. So if you type

```
http://example.com
```

Apache will receive the request and try to match the Host header

```
Host: example.com
```

with it's Virtual Host definitions. If it finds a a match, it will the use whatever is listed in the

```
DocumentRoot
```

In the example above

```
/var/www/example.com
```

This could be either an index file as defined within the configuration, or a directory index if they are permitted.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based

Comment: Thanks for your response....but my question is before apache to get the request....IP address should get resolved right....which is done by contacting DNS server or using "/etc/hosts"....but in my case...I have apache server on my local machine and a named virtual host....when I type ServerName in my browser...how is it able to resolve....I did not add any mapping to "/etc/hosts" file....

Comment: How does it know that the ServerName entered is my local machine??

Comment: What are you typing into your browser? What is the ServerName directive?

Comment: I mean to say....I submit "http://example.com" in the web browser.... My question is just...."How does IP - Domainname(example.com) mapping is done" here....though I did not change /etc/hosts

Comment: I understand your question, but without specifics as to what you're typing and what your VirtualHosts config is, I can't answer it.

I can guarantee if you type example.com into a browser with an empty hosts file, it's not showing your local apache server.

Comment: So here is my httpd conf contents and virtualhosts file contents

<IfModule passenger_module>
  NameVirtualHost *:80
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _default_
  </VirtualHost>
  Include /private/etc/apache2/passenger_pane_vhosts/*.conf
</IfModule>

contents of  /private/etc/apache2/passenger_pane_vhosts/*.conf


<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example
  DocumentRoot "<path>"
  RailsEnv development
  <Directory "<path>">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: oops....no formatting option in comments...I would reply to the same post rather

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is actually taking it from wherever your OS is storing the hostname, /etc/hostname on Ubuntu or /etc/sysconfig/network under RH-type distros

During install, I think it fills ServerName in by running the `hostname` command